# Copy to clipboard from Mono-ran programs does not work in Debian testing

Tags: linux, debian, kde, keepass, mono-framework

I was running KeePass (http://keepass.info/) using Mono on Debian Wheezy. I was able to copy usernames and passwords from KeePass to KDE using (mono? wine?) clipboard.

I found I needed to switch to testing release to get newer glibc. I did so and it works fine except now I cannot copy anything from KeePass to KDE clipboard.

How can I get functioning clipboard again?

P.S. I have switched to `testing` Debian release since then. The issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono), install the `xsel` package.

EDIT: It worked for me, but only for the "Copy User Name / Password" commands (still cannot copy from the entry notes).

Another solution could be exporting the password database into the 1.x format (.kdb) and use [KeePassX instead, which is a native Qt app](http://www.keepassx.org).

Comment: I have had `xsel` installed long before, used it in my scripts before KeePass use in fact. It does not help at all. Only autotype in KeyPass works, but no copying via clipboard in either direction.

Answer (score 0):

When copying from notes in KeePass the text ends up in the X server CLIPBOARD selection, but when pasting in a terminal text is retreived from the PRIMARY selection. There are software that should be able to handle this ([cpmerge](http://jonaspfannschmidt.com/cpmerge.html), [ClipIt](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt/) and maybe others) but this is the workaround I ended up using:

`xsel --clipboard | xsel --primary --input`

It simply retreives the content of the CLIPBOARD selection and puts it in the PRIMARY selection, ready to be pasted by clicking third mouse button or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1336762/how-do-i-copy-paste-from-the-system-clipboard-in-tmux-in-xterm-on-linux