# How do I copy / paste from the system clipboard in Tmux in xterm on Linux?

Tags: linux

I'd like to copy into and paste from the system (X11) clipboard when making a selection in Tmux and I'd like to bind these actions to the mouse; left click for copy and middle click for paste.

Answer (score 8):

For older versions of Tmux (<1.5) or other systems, try [`tmux-yank`](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank). For this specific case, however, Tmux very nicely integrates with the system.

In your `~/.tmux.conf`, add:

```
set -g mouse on
set -g set-clipboard external
bind -T root MouseUp2Pane paste
```

to enable mouse support, copying to the system clipboard, and bind a middle-click on a pane to paste.

And in your `~/.Xresources`:

```
xterm*selectToClipboard: true
xterm*disallowedWindowOps: 20,21,SetXProp
```

to let Xterm select to the system clipboard as well, and allow Tmux to modify the clipboard (a "window operation").

Then, to apply the changes to your `~/.Xresources`, run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` and restart Xterm and Tmux.

---

To support macOS and Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), we can add

```
run-shell $HOME/.tmux.conf.sh
```

to the `~/.tmux.conf`, and then create `~/.tmux.conf.sh` with the following contents:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

bind_copy=(bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane)

# `tmux_bind_copy pbcopy` will make selecting with the mouse (and then
# releasing the selection) in tmux pipe the selection to `pbcopy`
function tmux_bind_copy {
        tmux "${bind_copy[@]}" send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "$@"
}

if [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]]
then
    # Copy with pbcopy on macOS
    tmux_bind_copy pbcopy
fi

if [[ ! -z "$WSL_DISTRO_NAME" ]]
then
    # copy with Windows' clip.exe on WSL
    tmux_bind_copy /mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe
fi
```

Note that other “advanced” configuration choices can be made in `.tmux.conf.sh`, such as setting configuration values based on the current hostname, distribution, and so on; using `if-shell` is also an option, but is generally pretty clumsy in practice, so using a shell script is [an accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36953319/5719760).

Also note the weird syntax `"${bind_copy[@]}"`, which inserts the `$bind_copy` [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) without performing glob expansion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `$tmux -Version` `tmux 2.8`.
Before copying to clipboard, the magic is to press shift in advance and draw the area first (which you wanna copy to system clipboard), the area gets grey colored text background.

Afterwards  press the default hotkey to copy to system clipboard. I am using `Konsole` and there it is `Shift-Ctrl-C`.

Comment: This depends on the terminal emulator you're using (like xterm or Konsole or alacritty), and not on tmux. It can also include (in some selection modes) things like window borders if you have horizontal splits.

Comment: this solution works for `gnome-terminal` + `tmux` the same way.

Comment: it does not work on `xterm` + `tmux`

Comment: Works on tmux 2.8 + ROXTerm + Debian Linux!